# PDFBOX digit garble

Tags: java, pdfbox

I met some problems when I used PDFBOX to extract text. There are Tyep3 embedded fonts in my PDF, but the numbers cannot be displayed normally when extracting this part. Can someone give me some guidance? thank you

My version is 2.0.22

The correct output is [USD-001], the wrong output is [USD- ]

```
public static String readPDF(File file) throws IOException {
    RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream rbi = null;
    PDDocument pdDocument = null;
    String text = "";
    try {
        rbi = new RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream(file);
        PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(rbi);
        parser.setLenient(false);
        parser.parse();
        pdDocument = parser.getPDDocument();
        PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        text = textStripper.getText(pdDocument);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        rbi.close();
    }
    return text;
}
```

I tried to use PDFBOX to convert the PDF to an image and found that everything was fine. I just wanted to get it as normal text

PDFDebugger output
[image]

The pdf file : http://tmp.link/f/6249a07f6e47f

Comment: When using copy&paste from Adobe Reader, do you get the numbers there?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks for your answer, I tried to update and set sorting, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @mkl Thank you for your answer, in using copy and paste can get the correct value. And i used the PDFBOX DEBUGE and I found a problem. I found the glyphs 0 and 1, but the Unicode Character was empty. I don't understand why numbers can be correctly displayed when converted to pictures, but not when extracted from text

Comment: It's two different things. One is the visual representation of the code, the other one is the character for that code. Some PDFs don't have both. It might be a PDFBox bug, but it might also be that Adobe Reader is using some heuristics to get text. That is why we need the PDF.

Comment: *"in using copy and paste can get the correct value."* - [... checking ...] Indeed, but only for a short time. I originally had an end-of-2021 Reader version here which could not copy&paste the digits in question from your PDF. Because of your claim I updated the Reader, and now it can extract those digits... This sounds like there is some special twist to those digits. If I find the time, I'll try and inspect the file next week.

Comment: As an aside, there is an issue in the PDF objects cross reference table at the end of the document that will likely cause issue if the file is used in workflows with multiple digital signatures.

Comment: Your file uses /ActualText which we don't support (in the content stream near `0.74937 0 0 0.74937 132.47461 760.988 Tm`). This is a known issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4532 which sadly won't be fixed soon.

Comment: It uses **ActualText**, yes, but that's something Adobe Reader supported for quite a time now. Thus, I assume, there is some additional complication.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of aspects of this file making text extraction difficult.

First of all the font itself boycotts text extraction. In its **ToUnicode** stream we find the mappings:

```
1 begincodespacerange
<00> <ff> endcodespacerange
2 beginbfchar
<22> <0000> <23> <0000> endbfchar
```

I.e. the two character codes of interest both are mapped to U+0000, not to U+0030 ('0') and U+0031 ('1') as they should have been.

Also the **Encoding** is not helping at all:

```
<</Type/Encoding/Differences[ 0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g0/g121/g122]>>
```

The glyph names `/g121` and `/g122` don't have a standardized meaning either.

PdfBox for text extraction works with these two properties of a font and, therefore, fails here.

Adobe Acrobat, on the other hand, also makes use of **ActualText** during text extraction.

In the file there are such entries. Unfortunately, though, they are erroneous, like this for the digit '0':

```
/P <</MCID 23>>/Span <</ActualText<FEFF0030>>>BDC
```

The **BDC** instruction only expects a single name and a single dictionary. The above sequence of name, dictionary, name, and dictionary, therefore, is invalid.

Due to that Adobe Acrobat also used to not extract the actual text here. Only recently, probably as recently as the early 2022 releases, Acrobat started extracting a '0' here.

---

Actually one known "trick" to prevent one's PDFs to be text extracted by regular text extractor programs is to add incorrect **ToUnicode** and **Encoding** information but correct **ActualText** entries.

So it's possible the error in your file is actually an application of this trick, maybe even by design with the erroneous **ActualText** twist to lead text extractors with some **ActualText** support astray while still allowing copy&paste from Adobe Acrobat.